# How can I force a subpage in my mobile app to reload an external domain iframe and use the website cookie?

Tags: html, cordova, jquery-mobile, iframe, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using a jquery mobile app development tool that makes use of the Cordova API, and it's being developed in HTML5.

I have 3 buttons in the main app page (menu) and I want each of them to open a direct link of my website inside my App (cant be direct link or it leaves app and visits with browser)

For this matter, I have created 3 subpages inside my app that load an iframe with the link I want to display from my website as follows :

```
<div id="dashboard" data-role="page">
  <div role="main" class="ui-content"></div>
  <iframe src="http://example.com/dashboard/" name="frame1" scrolling="yes" frameborder="no" align="center" height="100%" width="100%" style="margin-top:-40px; display:block; height:600px;"></iframe></div></div>
```

The problem is that once I login to my website through any of the mobile app subpages, when I visit any of them the content is never reloaded, so basically if I login in one of the subpages all the other will still ask me for the login again.

How can I force each of the subpages accessed inside my app to reload the iframe inside them every time I click the button with href to #subpage ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the login page, you can edit the login page to redirect once is loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> window.location = 'login.html'; </script>
```

Comment: Tiffany thanks but I am already doing that.

The problem is that once I login I shouldn't need to do the same for every subpage , which doesn't let me access any of my links directly .

The login page is set to redirect to index.php, but i want my subpages to load in iframe page1.php, page2.php, etc.

Since when I visit each subpage I am faced with the same login again for each, this isn't possible and it always ends up going to index.php.

THe subpages shouldn't be showing the login again once it's logged in from #subpage1.

Comment: If you navigate inside the iframe that contains the login.html, your main url will not change and you'll have index.html in your navigation bar.

So if you refresh you will refresh the index.html page, and you will be back to your login page. Short answer, avoid using iframes